# How do I connect a new remote to my ps4?

Tags: ps4

Just bought a ps4 remote. How do I connect it to my ps4? I tried pushing the PlayStation button & connecting the usb cord. No luck.

Comment: Do other remotes work on that PS4? Have you tried that remote on other PS4s? Did you buy it new or used?

Comment: Remote that came w ps4 works, but brand-new remote not working.

Comment: Sounds like a dodgy remote. I'd return it.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of connecting the PS4 controller is to connect it through USB and pressing the PS Button. If that fails for you, you can try to manually connect it through bluetooth. To do that, you have to make sure the controller is off, and press the PS Button and the Share button at the same time. The light on the controller should start to blink. Next, you will have to go into the bluetooth settings of the PS4 and find the controller and pair with it.

I have had to manually connect it through bluetooth before when the USB method wasn't working.